# How to count twice in the same statement

Tags: sql

I have a table where each entry represents a buy.

The columns of interest are `Items`, `Customer`.

I want to output

```
<Items, total items sold, total distinct client that bought it>
```

The furthest I got is

```
select item, customer, count(customer) as `Total Sold`
from my_table
group by item, customer
order by item
```

This will output

```
item1, customer1, total_bought_by_customer1
item1, customer2, total_bought_by_customer2
```

What I want is

```
item1, total_bought, total_distinct_costumer_who_bought_it
```

How can I do this? Without joins.

Comment: Tried `select item, count(customer), count(DISTINCT customer)`?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Also, maybe there is a mistake in `costumer` and `customer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the customer from the grouping (assume costomer is a typo),

```
select item, 
  count(*) as total_bought, 
  count(distinct customer) as total_distinct_custumer_who_bought_it
from my_table
group by item
order by item
```